# Where to deploy Spring boot application with H2 database

Tags: java, database, spring-boot, deployment

I am working on a web application which will serve as an SQL injection learning platform with multiple levels in spring boot and react. I am using PostreSQL as my main database, but I also wanted a lightweight solution for a vulnerable database on which the injections will occure. I was going to choose H2, but it isn't supported on Heroku where I wanted to deploy my application, as I worked with it in the past and it's already familiar.

So the question is: What other platform could I use to work with H2 or should I choose something else instead of H2, and if yes, what?

Answer (score 0):

The way I handle this is to use spring-bean "profiles"

```
default
```

or

```
!default
```

I use H2 all the time for local-development mode (using 'default' spring bean profile to achieve this).

Now, we do not over-use spring-profiles.  We have default and !default.  And that is is.

All my JPA stuff works with H2.